# How to import MSG/EML email files into Outlook via the API?

Tags: api, email, outlook

I have a directory hierarchy full of EML/MSG email data files. These files can be imported into MS Outlook 2010 (desktop version) one at a time, but I am looking for a way to automate this. I need to create each folder as an Outlook folder, and import email datafiles into these Outlook folders. Anyone aware of an [Outlook 2010 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458122(v=office.14).aspx) that allows for creating folders & importing files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create new folders in Outlook, use `MAPIFolder.Folders.Add`.

Outlook Object Model does not directly support importing EML or MSG files (or any other files for that matter).

For MSG files you can

1. Use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) and the [OpenIMsgOnIStg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815715(v=office.15).aspx) function to open an MSG file. You can then create a new message in the target folder and copy properties either using `IMessage.CopyTo` (keep in mind that standalone MSG files do not correctly process named properties in `CopyTo`) or read the properties one at a time and set them on the target message explicitly.
2. Outlook Object Model can open MSG files using `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` (it will be created in an unsent state) and using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`. You can then move the message (`MailItem.Move`) into the target folder

For the EML files, you can

1. Use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) and the built-in Outlook interface ([IComverterSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960231(v=office.15).aspx)). You can play with that interface in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (click IConverterSession button - I am its author).
2. Outlook Object Model does not support EML files at all. The best you can do is create your own parser and copy the EML file into Outlook one MIME header/part at a time.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) is an option (I am its author), you can use [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Import` method - it imports MSG (`olMsg`) and EML (`olRfc822`) files (as well as a few other formats).

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT '//or you can call Logon
  set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  set Msg = Inbox.Items.Add
  Msg.Sent = true '//since Import does not copy this property
  Msg.Import("c:\temp\test.eml", 1024) ' //1024 is olRfc822
  Msg.Save
```

Comment: Fantastic in depth answer, thank you very much! I'll check out your resources and get back..